# Positional Inverted Index in Python

Tags: python

I recently developed a Python program that makes an inverted index out of terms in a certain document. I now want to create position postings, such as

```
to, 993427:
⟨ 1, 6: ⟨7, 18, 33, 72, 86, 231⟩;

2, 5: ⟨1, 17, 74, 222, 255⟩; 4, 5: ⟨8, 16, 190, 429, 433⟩; 5, 2: ⟨363, 367⟩;

7, 3: ⟨13, 23, 191⟩; …⟩
```

I know the code is not complete as described above, I'm just trying to implement functionality.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
from collections import Counter
import pprint
import re
import sys
import string
import fileinput
try: 
    reduce
except: 
    from functools import reduce
try:
    raw_input
except:
    raw_input = input


def readIn(fileglob): #Reads in multiple files and strips punctation/uppercase.
    texts, words = {}, set()
    for txtfile in (fileglob):
        with open(txtfile, 'r') as splitWords:
            txt = splitWords.read().lower().split()
            txt = str(txt)
            txt = re.findall(r'\w+', txt)
            words |= set(txt)
            texts[txtfile.split('\\')[-1]] = txt
    return texts, words

def search(indexes): # Inverted index, based off the book and the web.
    return reduce(set.intersection,
                  (index[word] for word in indexes),
                  set(texts.keys()))

def getWordBins(posOfWords):
    cnt = Counter()
   for word in posOfWords:
       cnt[posOfWords] += 1
    return cnt


def main(fileList, topWords):
    tempArray = []
    for x in range(1,len(fileList)):
        tempArray.append(fileList[x])


    texts, words = readIn(tempArray)
    index = {word:set(txt
                         for txt, wrds in texts.items() if word in wrds)
                for word in words}


    test =({k + " " + str(len(v)) + " " + str(sorted(v)) for k,v in index.items()})

    txt = readIn(fileList)
    posWord = getWordBins(txt)
    for key, value in posWord.most_common(topWords):
        print key, value


    #Writes out the information requested to a ".idx" file.
    doc = open("document.idx", "w") 
    doc.write("# INPUT DOCUMENT REFERENCE LEGEND\n")
    for fileNumber in range(1, len(fileList)):
        doc.write(str(fileNumber) + "\t" + fileList[fileNumber] + "\n")
    doc.write("# INVERTED INDEX RESULTS\n")
    tempTest = []
    for x in test:
        tempTest.append(x.split(" "))
    for x in tempTest:
        tempStr = ""
        for y in x:
            tempStr += y + "\t"
        doc.write(tempStr + "\n")
    doc.close


main(sys.argv, sys.argv)
```

This is what I have so far, the only new functionality is the getWordBins function, and the loop:

```
    txt = readIn(fileList)
    posWord = getWordBins(txt)
    for key, value in posWord.most_common(topWords):
        print key, value
```

Now, what happens when I try to run the code is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Intro3.py", line 82, in <module>
    main(sys.argv, sys.argv)
  File "Intro3.py", line 60, in main
    posWord = getWordBins(txt)
  File "Intro3.py", line 41, in getWordBins
    cnt[posOfWords] += 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Any guidance with this troubling error is gladly received. It is not a dictionary, so why the error?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: That example has a set, not a dictionary. What is the difference?

Comment: A `dictionary` cannot be hashed and therefore cannot be used as a `key` to another `dictionary` (or itself for that matter!).

Comment: What is `posOfWords`? Type? Also, even a `set` is not hashable, because a `set` is mutable type. And, whatever is a mutable type, cannot be hashed, hence cannot be stored in a dictionary.

Comment: But do note, the immutable variant of `set()` -- `frozenset()` -- is hashable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're doing:

```
cnt[posOfWords] += 1
```

I think you might mean:

```
cnt[word] += 1
```

Your readin function also returns a dict and a set, so your txt variable is a tuple of (`dict`, `set`)

So your problem boils down to trying to use a tuple holding a dict as a key (which I doubt is your intent). And it wouldn't work for `cnt[word] += 1`, because that would still be trying to use a dict as a key too. You need to do this, probably:

```
txt, _ = readIn(fileList)
```

and then this might work:

```
cnt[word] += 1
```